# How to generate .apklib and .apk in same maven build?

Tags: android, maven-3, maven-plugin, pom.xml, apklib

So I am using Android Maven Plugin to generate apklib snapshot for one of my library project. 
But the library project is also self sufficient to run on its own so I am thinking that may be we should generate .apklib and .apk both at the same time using maven.

Here is the pom configuration.

```
<groupId>com.comanyname.apps.lib</groupId>
<artifactId>MyProject-lib</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>apklib</packaging>
<name>MyProject-lib</name>
```

I tried adding another packaging like this

```
<groupId>com.comanyname.apps.lib</groupId>
<artifactId>MyProject-lib</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>apklib</packaging>
<packaging>apk</packaging>
<name>MyProject-lib</name>
```

I don't know if it is possible. I can switch the packaging to apk/apklib one at a time though.

Comment: Did you get any error while adding another packaging or does it just override the first one?

Comment: I got an error when I added the second packaging so that approach didn't work. Sorry I should have wrote that in my original question post. I realize it after posting the question.

Comment: Well, the reason for that is because groupID, artifactId and version are used to uniquely identify a maven artifact

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I was able to create apk and apklib by creating two profiles.

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>local</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <projectVersion>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</projectVersion>
                <packagingType>apk</packagingType>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>build</id>
            <properties>
                <projectVersion>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</projectVersion>
                <packagingType>apklib</packagingType>
            </properties>
        </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: This is a very bad practice and not how you suppose to use Android library project and Maven.

Answer (score 2):

The recommended approach is to create two projects:

1. Project A is a library project (packagingType of apklib). It contains all the code, resources and assets.
2. Project B is a standard Android project (packagingType of apklib), that depends on Project A. It contains no code, resources or assets (although you can add some if you want to).
3. Optionally, you can have a parent project with Project A & B as modules. Then whenever you build the parent project, both the apk and apklib are built.

I use this approach with my own projects, and it works very well. I also add a test project as a third module, which depends on the apklib.

I added simplified samples of the project structure on https://gist.github.com/4224133.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! It helped a lot to finally split of a project I use: [MapChange](https://github.com/johnjohndoe/MapChange/commit/e48fdfd0d3683994c458a26993a249061d9bf3b1).

Answer (score 1):

#### "But the Library project is also self sufficient to run on its own."

This is not possible, at least not support by official Android SDK, check out [the dev guide](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects) to see what is an Android library project:

> However, a library project differs from an standard Android application project in that you cannot compile it directly to its own .apk and run it on an Android device. Similarly, you cannot export the library project to a self-contained JAR file, as you would do for a true library. Instead, you must compile the library indirectly, by referencing the library in the dependent application and building that application.

#### "I can switch the packaging to apk/apklib one at a time though."

This is probably doable by android-maven-plugin, as Android library project has similar project structure to a standard Android application project, stated in dev guide:

> Structurally, a library project is similar to a standard Android application project. For example, it includes a manifest file at the project root, as well as src/, res/ and similar directories. The project can contain the same types of source code and resources as a standard Android project, stored in the same way. For example, source code in the library project can access its own resources through its R class.

I haven't tested it by myself, if it is true, I would consider this is as a bug in *android-maven-plugin* as it dose not respect `android.library=true` set in *project.properties* file. If it is a library project, *android-maven-plugin* should give error or at least a warning when you are trying to build it using `<packaging>apk</packaging>`.

Comment: I have quickly tried myself. Yes, android-maven-plugin does not respect android.library=true in project.properties. I have create a issue [here](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/issues/detail?id=309).

Comment: So I see you are not using latest android-maven-plugin which is 3.3.2 but even then I was able to produce .apk after setting android.library=true in my project.properties. I think project.properties is used only be eclipse project structure but not by maven. My guess is that maven is not reading project.properties when it is building projects and the reason for that is we do define the apk level etc in pom.xml etc so basically maven builds based on what is defined in pom.xml. On the topic of apklib vs apk I also read the same but as u can see apklib has similar project structure.

Comment: Can we solve this by using profiles in maven? So e.g. a build profile will generate .apklib and development profile generates .apk etc.?

Comment: 1. As dev guide stated library project can not compile/run on it own, so android-maven-plugin should respect this consideration and correct this in new release. 2 Even though there is a way to do that, it is highly NOT recommended as this violate Maven build Lifecycle. In Java, we don't use one project build both war and jar file.